# android : javamail FolderClosedException IMAP4rev1 Server logging out

Tags: android, jakarta-mail, imap

I am using javamail to connect to yahoo server and read mails. I connect , open the folder and read the mails. Only for one particular email id i am always getting the following exception when i am trying to read. The exception happens after opening the folder while reading unreadmail count.

I tested 3 other yahoo mail ids and it is working.

stack trace

09-11 17:06:42.514: E/MailboxReader(28857): MailboxReader() MessagingException: * BYE IMAP4rev1 Server logging out
09-11 17:06:42.514: E/MailboxReader(28857): idg.javax.mail.FolderClosedException: * BYE IMAP4rev1 Server logging out
09-11 17:06:42.514: E/MailboxReader(28857):     at com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPFolder.getUnreadMessageCount(IMAPFolder.java:1526)
09-11 17:06:42.514: E/MailboxReader(28857):     at com.isaacdanielgroup.sempostmark.MailboxReader.readMail(MailboxReader.java:301)

Comment: I have seen Yahoo's servers occasionally log people out due to bugs in their IMAP sever.  This is usually accompanied by a [SERVERBUG] tag in their OK response after the BYE.

Comment: Please post the [debug output](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#debug).